# Ionic Modal bottom spacing

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I can't manage to set a bottom spacing between my modal and the screen's bottom limit! In my CSS, I've set the "ion-modal-view" elements CSS height and width to some percentage and gave values to left, right, top and bottom accordingly, everything works as expected, my modal is centered, but I can't detach it from the bottom.

Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I've managed to get it working by wrapping my `ion-modal-view` with a `div` that applies a `min-height: 0;` directive on the `modal` class, this made my custom margin effective.

```
<div class="adic-modal">
    <ion-modal-view class="adic-popup">
        <!--some content-->
    </ion-modal-view>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.adic-modal .modal {
    min-height: 0 !important;
}

.adic-popup {
    width: 90%;
    height: 60%;
    top: 20%;
    bottom: 20%;
    right: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

I need to know though if what I did is the right approach.

Comment: You sire are a genius, thank you! I had been struggling with this for a long time.